# sudo apt-get update not working after install PPAs

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, ppa, update-manager

after install some PPAs when ever I do `sudo apt-get update` the output is

```
Hit:1 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://repo.steampowered.com/steam precise InRelease                                                                                                                  
Hit:3 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                                                                                          
Hit:4 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                                                                                             
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                                                                                                
Ign:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/grumbel/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease       
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kelleyk/emacs/ubuntu bionic InRelease        
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/grumbel/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release                                                       
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Get:9 https://qgis.org/ubuntu bionic InRelease [3,693 B]
Err:9 https://qgis.org/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 51F523511C7028C3
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/grumbel/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: https://qgis.org/ubuntu bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 51F523511C7028C3
E: The repository 'https://qgis.org/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: I opened http://ppa.launchpad.net/grumbel/ppa/ubuntu is a browser and can quickly see it doesn't support bionic (18.04), in fact as support ended early 2017 - I'd not use it myself.  PPA's are 3rd party sources, and responsibility to vet if they are safe/unsafe/trusted/maintained is all on you.  As that PPA doesn't support bionic, plus un-maintained for some time, I'd suggest removing it.  *I only looked at first issue*

Comment: If I do [this] and it causes problems....revert [this]!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [grumbel ppa](https://launchpad.net/~grumbel/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) does not show any packages for bionic. When you look at the launchpad page for this ppa, under "Overview of published packages" there is a filter where you can select the Ubuntu version and bionic is not listed.

You can delete this ppa by running the following command:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/grumbel*
```

Also, I don't know how you installed the qgis.org repository so you will have to do one of the following.

First, if you have a file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` for this repository, edit the file and change "ubuntu" to "debian", save the file and then run: `sudo apt update`.

However, if you edited your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file to add this repository, edit this file and **on the qgis.org repository line**, change "ubuntu" to "debian". and then run: `sudo apt update`

[Click here for more information on installing the qgis.org repository.](https://www.gis-blog.com/how-to-install-qgis-3-on-ubuntu/)

Alternatively, you can remove the offending ppas in Software&Updates.

Comment: add-apt-repository has a removal command. Better to suggest that then removing a directory. Or even use Software&Updates > other to remove offending ppa

Comment: @doug The `--remove` option only removes the contents of the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` file and does not remove the actual file. Using the `rm` command completely removes the file. There is no need to keep a file for a ppa that has not been updated since 2017 and likely will not offer any updates in the future.

Comment: @mchid and @doug that you so much `sudo apt-get update` works again